# TortoiseSVN copying data from one location to other with complete history

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to move code from one branch to another with complete history.
Like from
eg. `http://server:port/java/branch1/version1/service`
location to 
eg. `http://server.port/branch2/version2/service`
location.

Im using TortoiseSVN for basic checkout and commit operations. Is it possible to do this using tortoiseSVN ?
I also tried dumping branch1 by command line, but it existed with error.

How do I move this code with history ?

Answer (score 0):

1. SVN-branches are the same objects with own URL and, in common, part of repository tree.
2. Any part of SVN-repo can be [moved](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html) inside it (see URL-URL version of command and 3-rd example)

Thus, something like `svn move FROM TO -m "Cross-branch movement"` do the trick